# Wire length for the manufacture of the frame

Tags: geometry

Find the length of the wire for the manufacture of the tetrahedron framework bounded by the planes $$x + y + z = 4, x + y-z = 2, x-y + z = 2, -x + y + z = 2$$
Will finding a volume of a tetrahedron help me in solution?

Answer (score 0):

No. What you need is to fins the intersections of each combinations of three planes. You have 4 possible combinations. Solving them will get you the vertices. Then take the 6 possible combinations of vertices, and this will give you the sides. Get the lengths of those sides, add them together, and you get your answer. For example, using the first three planes, you get $(x_1,y_1,z_1)=(2,1,1)$ (if I did not make any mistakes). If you use the first two and the last plane, you get $(x_2,y_2,z_2)=(1,2,1)$. Then the distance between those vertices is $\sqrt{(2-1)^2+(1-2)^2+(1-1)^2}=\sqrt 2$

Answer (score 0):

If it's not a regular tetrahedron then no. You can scale one face arbitrarily and pull the point not on that face orthogonally to it to get another tetrahedron with arbitrarily long edges.

To see this imagine a regular tetrahedron with each edge of unit length. The sum of the side lengths is six. Now we scale one face so that each edge is of length $0 < \epsilon$ which we assume is small. In order to preserve the volume we need to increase the height proportionally and so the length of the three edges not on the face would grow by size $1/\epsilon$. This would give the length of all the edges to be $3/\epsilon + 3 \epsilon$. Since $3\epsilon$ is very small and $3/\epsilon$ is very large this term dominates for small $\epsilon$ and we see that we can make the sum of the lengths of the edges very large and still have unit volume.